# Stop mysql query if it too long

Tags: mysql

How do I automatically interrupting long queries in the mysql, if it possible?
I'm understand, that I need optimize queries instead of. But now I have access on database server only.

Comment: "But now I have access on database server only." that's enough. You can optimize queries as well

Comment: Queries executing on another server

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I routinely kill MySQL queries that have been alive for "too long"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189039/how-do-i-routinely-kill-mysql-queries-that-have-been-alive-for-too-long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are optimizing your queries you can interrupt them by [killing the corresponding thread](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not stop a query once it has been executed.

> I'm understand, that I need optimize
>   queries instead of.

That's the way you should go.

**Other Possibility:**

You may want to have a look at **[SQL Transactions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions)** if applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in mysql to limit how long query can run and then timeout. Have "long query killer" script which catches kills and reports bad queries by eg. looking at SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST time property. You can do it via stored procedure and call it on scheduled time or via application that is connecting to mysql also on scheduled basis.

Answer (score 0):

Try kill long query process time:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $process_id = $row["Id"];
        if ($row["Time"] > 200 ) {
            $sql="KILL $process_id";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
```