# Kill or stop MySQL queries after quitting PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a statistics server at work that sometimes gets quite slow because of the amount of queries run on it.

Our marketing team uses it as its main stats tool. Some people in the team sometimes just quit the script before it ended (by closing their browser or tab). Meanwhile, SQL queries continue to be executed.

How can I kill or stop the associated queries of a PHP script when someone closes or leaves this script?

We of course do not want to kill these queries by hand (which we already do) but automatically as soon as the person quits the script.

Most of our statistics scripts are based on precalculations done every night for the heaviest of them, and these ones are not problematic for us. For the others, we have not yet implemented precalculations and we wanted to be able to kill orphan queries before doing it.

Comment: Check this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189039/how-do-i-routinely-kill-mysql-queries-that-have-been-alive-for-too-long

Comment: Perhaps a better indication of the progress of the SQL queries would keep people from quitting the web pages as much.  Another alternative would be to make the SQL queries asynchronous, so people wouldn't have to wait for the results.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. However most of the scripts we run have one single enormous query parsng through 10 or 20 million rows. So there is no real way to know that n% of the query has been reached I guess.

Comment: have you ever thought about doing some precalculations like storing some things that only have to be calculated one time and will never change?

Comment: @ITroubs: most of our statistics scripts are indeed based on precalculations done every night for the heaviest of them, and these ones are not problematic for us. For the others, we have not yet implemented precalculations and we wanted to be able to kill orphan queries before doing it.

Comment: there is a way to find out in php if a connection was closed using connection_aborted() but to use that you'd have to figure out a way to make an asynchronous call to the mysql database and then loop while connection_aborted returns false or your query is still running. and you'd have to figure out how to abort your asynchronous call to your mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the connection from the browser to your server is still open, using the [Connection Handling mechanisms](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php), and react appropriately.

Note however that any SQL queries that have *started* so far will run to completion - if they are complex, this can take a while, and there's no in-band way to terminate them: you'd need to watch which thread runs what and harvest the abandoned threads periodically.

Comment: That is the problem, we want to trigger a kill query once the user quits his page. I think we have found a way to do it:
- once connection is established, get connection_id() in SQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)
- store it in some variable
- once the user quits the page, issue a js event that triggers a KILL query based on the previous variable

Comment: @cellover: Issuing a JS event when they close the browser? Good luck - most browsers will kill `onunload` event handlers if they run for too long...

Answer (score 1):

You sometimes need to be able to kill a query that goes on too long. If you want to do that in your OS, you can do this-- it is fairly safe as MySQL runs all these in child processes. In Unix, this is `ps` and `kill`.

You can also use [MysqlAdmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html) to do it, and it should be basically the same across OSes. You  get a list of the processes that are running:

```
$ mysqladmin processlist # password if necessary
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 2  | root | localhost |    | Query   | 0    |       | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

Then look up `mysqladmin kill` to remove them.

*EDIT*

Okay, if it's about detecting the browser closed, I see a few approaches:

1. Check out PHP's [connection handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php). It looks like you can register a handle that is called if the user closes the browser.
2. If the handler doesn't get called, maybe you can call an interstitial page that says simply "Running query..." and then the rendering of that page can sit in a loop and wait for the query to complete or the connection to end. If the query completes, redirect to a "results" page, and if the connection goes down, manually kill the query (see above).
3. If those approaches prove fruitless, there is another option. The browser offers a Javascript "on unload" event that gets fired in the browser closest. A quick Ajax post from that could off the long-running query.

(Assignment: discuss the merits and disadvantages of all approaches.)

None of these strike me as beautiful, but with some work they can be made to work. To be honest, when we had this problem we just kept a processlist up and killed what looked like errant queries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes we know how to kill the queries, we just want them to be automated killed once a user quits the page, and we don't want to kill queries that have gone too long unless it's for a good reason.

Comment: Added some thoughts about how to detect when the user "quits the page".

Answer (score 0):

The best way (I think) is to close connection immediately after using.
Also wait_timeout session variable can be set (for example decreased to 20 seconds); in this case connection will be closed automatically.

Comment: The problem is that connection should be closed once the query has finished, with sometimes never happend ^^

Comment: Why cannot you close it manually in your php script? And about the wait_timeout variable - it forces server to close connection if one isn't active for a time.

Comment: We can't activate it because we don't know at what step user will quit the script. As for wait_timeout variable, we don't want to kick the user out if he is waiting for his result to show up even if this takes 1 hour.

Comment: i think the bigger problem is that you can't estimate the maximal time the user needs for his query.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there isn't much you can do if they are just hitting the close button on their browser.  Listed already are some built in functions that will check the session.  Maybe try caching the most often used queries.  Google "caching php mysql".

If this doesn't work you could build it with AJAX and every time a query is finished - the server will send back a message keeping the user updated on the progress of their request.  This will likely reduce the amount of people just giving up on their session.

Comment: Yes that could diminish the amount of users quitting the script prematurely, but it would work on scripts that have a large amount of queries run which is rarely the case here. We usually have more about 2 or 3 queries running in each script.

Answer (score 0):

With some colleagues of mine, we came up with the following idea:

- once MySQL connection is established, get connection_id() in SQL - [CONNECTION_ID() doc on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)
- store it in some variable
- once the user quits the page (may it be by quitting it or loading another page), issue a js event that triggers a KILL query based on the previous variable

We will have this tested in the next few hours, I will update here as soon as we are sure it works.

Comment: I'm excited. I hope you're done soon.